# How can I make Tab insert tabs at the start of the line only, and spaces after text?

Tags: key-bindings, indentation

## What I want to achieve

I would like to setup vim such that tabs are inserted on lines until another character is inserted, after which, further tabulation results in spaces (similarly to expantab).

## Example

```
function f(arg x) {
\t    if (x > 0) {
\t    \t    y.=.........x
\t    \t    elephants.=.x
\t    \t    friends.=...x

\t    mat = (
\t    \t    x.....0b11..x
\t    \t    x+1...x-1...x
\t    \t    y.....x.....z&0xFF
\t    )

\t    return x
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an expression mapping:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> getline('.')[: col('.') - 2] =~ '^\s*$' ? "\<Tab>" : repeat(' ', shiftwidth())
```

This looks a bit more complicated than it is: the `<expr>` tells Vim to evaluate the right-hand side as a VimScript expression, rather than just a list of keys.

In the expression we use `getline('.')[: col('.') - 2] =~ '^\s*$'` to check if everything before the cursor is whitespace; `getline('.')` gets the current line, and `col('.')` the cursor position, and `=~` tests if this matches a regular expression.

If it's all whitespace, return a `<Tab>`, which inserts a tab if `expandtab` is off, or spaces if it's enabled. Otherwise it always inserts `shiftwidth` space.

A little bit more expanded version in "pseudo-code" (not valid VimScript and doesn't actually work, but looks a bit easier to read to understand what's going on):

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> s
    if getline('.')[: col('.') - 2] =~ '^\s*$'
        return "\<Tab>"
    else
        return repeat(' ', shiftwidth())
    endif
}
```

Comment: I realize the original title was not very explicit ; or perhaps it was the question which was too much. I Highly appreciate the detailed explanation of the answer. Thank you very much for both.

Comment: Uppon further testing, I've come to believe somethings missing. I have improved (for my sake at least) on your solution so to have "the spaces" align with the tabs and shift width (unlike your original answer which adds shift width spaces regardless of alignment) :
`
inoremap <expr> <Tab> getline('.')[: col('.') - 2] =~ '^\s*$' ? "\<Tab>" : repeat(' ', (virtcol('.') % shiftwidth()) + 1)
`
Would you be so kind to add this to your original post as it has the desired effect I was going for ? I would have been able to come up with this line without you, once again, thank you very much.

Comment: Ah yeah @NRagot, it should do that. In a quick test your solution doesn't quite seem to work correct in all cases, but maybe I'm doing it wrong. Need to look at it when it's not 2am  I actually stuck this in my own vimrc, so I'll be sure to look at it soon!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Martin's answer, the right expression seems to be

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> getline('.')[: col('.') - 2] =~ '^\s*$' ? "\<Tab>" : repeat(' ', shiftwidth() - ((virtcol('.') - 1) % shiftwidth()))
```

which inserts the same amount of spaces as when using hard tabs.

---

The difference is the 2nd argument to the `repeat` function - how many times do we want to repeat the space character.

Empirically, pressing Tab does not always insert `shiftwidth` (from now on `sw` for the sake of brevity) spaces, but advances the cursor so that it ends up after the next `n*sw` position (at `n*sw+1`). This means that `pos mod sw` will be 1, or to put it differently, `pos-1 mod sw = 0` will be true at our new position. This is true at the beginning of the line as well, as the line starts at `pos` (that is, column) number 1.

Note that we are not talking about alignment here, because if we stand on a position where `pos-1 mod sw` equals 0, Tab will advance us the full `sw` spaces.

So let's see how this should look like:

- `pos-1 mod sw = 0` -> insert `sw` spaces
- `pos-1 mod sw = 1` -> insert `sw-1` spaces
- ...
- `pos-1 mod sw = sw-1` -> insert 1 space

It is obvious from here that the correct repeat count should be `sw - (pos-1 mod sw)`.

Comment: This answer could be improved by highlighting the differing expression and explaining how it adjusts the computation